# how to set AWS variables by using environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I folllow this tutorial http://pjambet.github.com/blog/direct-upload-to-s3/. Pretty much stuck in the setting the AWS variable. The tut says I have to set the variables as below

```
export S3_BUCKET=<YOUR BUCKET>
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<YOUR KEY>
export AWS_SECRET_KEY_ID=<YOUR SECRET KEY>
```

But it doesn't mention where to set those of variable.
Could anyone point me out ? Thanks

Comment: You can put them to your `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc` or whatever config file your system uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type it in the command line. [Export command.](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Export_Variables)